# Looking for LTspice model LTC2644 .lib file

Tags: ltspice

I am looking for LTspice model LTC2644 .lib file

As this model is not available with me in my LTspice tool library and further I need the same to create LTspce simulation circuity for PWM to 0 to 10 V output analog conversation.

If any one of you possess, kindly share me the same.

Comment: Welcome! Have you tried to contact Analog Devices?

Answer (score 2):

You won't find one, it's a DAC and SPICE doesn't really simulate digital devices. Use a variable voltage source and simulate the output series resistance/capacitance.

You could also use a [b-source](https://ltwiki.org/index.php?title=B_sources_(common_examples)) with a floor function to simulate the quantization of a DAC.

Comment: The model of PWM to DAC is available in proteus VSM